# PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase Found but undefined method ::call()

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Hi i am working with Laravel 4.2.17 , PHPUnit 5.1.1 and PHP 5.6.16 .

I am using PHPStorm as My Editor .

When i go to app/tests/ExampleTest.php and run it i am getting the error .

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TestCase' not found in /..../app/tests/ExampleTest.php on line 3
```

Then i changed `TestCase` to `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` Now the ExampleTest.php looks like this

```
class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }

}
```

Now the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` calls is identified .

But when i try to do

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->call("POST","test");
}
```

It is saying that

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ExampleTest::call()
```

I checked the larval documents and in there

```
Calling A Route From A Test

You may easily call one of your routes for a test using the call method:

$response = $this->call('GET', 'user/profile');

$response = $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content);
```

SO i am not sure what i am doing wrong .

I also tried by updating the composer , but no luck . :( :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot access `call` is because you are no longer extending `TestCase` which provides it. I suggest you revert back to `extends TestCase` and run your tests again. You should make sure to run the test from the root directory by using `phpunit app/tests`.

Running `composer dump-autoload` also first, just in case it's an autoloading issue.